# How to increase the size of the /dev/shm in docker container

Tags: docker, containers

Currently When I create new docker container the size of the shared memory directory is limited to 64MB. But, I need to increase this size since my application depend on this shared memory.
Is there any way to increase the size of /dev/shm in docker container?
I heard that the 64MB is hard coded in the docker code, How to install docker from source and change the value of the /dev/shm?

Comment: I had to struggle to find this. However, it's exactly my problem. Adding shm_open and mmap here in hopes Google catches this SO post and makes other's lives easier. That's how I backed into this issue, not knowing anything about mapping the files to /dev/shm.

Answer (score 178):

If you're using docker-compose, you can set the `your_service.shm_size` value if you want your container to use that /dev/shm size when *running* or `your_service.build.shm_size` when *building*.

Example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  your_service:
    build:
      context: .
      shm_size: '2gb' <-- this will set the size when BUILDING
    shm_size: '2gb' <-- when RUNNING
```

[Link to source](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6333).

Comment: this answer shows the differences of using shm_size in build case and service case. I wonder why the answer was not accepted!

Comment: Because there is no mention of docker-compose in the question.

Comment: Putting `shm_size` in `your_service.shm_size` solved my problem. While others keep saying put it in `build`

Comment: noob question, what is the your_service here? the name of the service? or should i keep the same?

Comment: It is the name that you gave the service in the `docker-compose.yml` file. This only applies when using docker-compose.

Answer (score 119):

You can modify shm size by passing the optional parameter `--shm-size` to `docker run` command. The default is 64MB.

eg:

```
docker run -it --shm-size=256m oracle11g /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is not working on debian 8 with docker 1.11.0. Not working as build params either!

Comment: Does increasing the shm size have any negative impact? (besides increased resource usage)

Comment: This worked for me, but I set it to 2gb: --shm-size=2gb

Comment: This solution is helpful (works also with `=` sign replaced by space). However, on Docker Desktop for Windows, for `docker build` (rather than `docker run`) it stopped working at some moment (perhaps after upgrade but I can't prove it). I realized it was caused by activating Docker Buildkit. This thread https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/418 shows it does not support `--shm-size` option. Solution was to permanently set system variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` and everything returned to normal.

Comment: This `docker run --shm-size` argument is also recommended by Ray (`ray.init()`, which needs it to run out-of-core and it also recommends _"[..] to set this to more than 30% of available RAM."_

Answer (score 19):

If you use docker-compose to set up your docker environment, it is also possible to set the shared memory in the `docker-compose.yml` configuration file:

```
build:
  context: .
  shm_size: '2gb'
```

More info in the compose-file docs:

- [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#shm_size)
- [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#shm_size)

Answer (score 11):

If anybody is using an older docker version prior 1.10.0 and cannot upgrade for some reason, there is a workaround I used to set shm-size which works fine for me (you need sudo-rights to create the mount on the host):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/dockershm
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /mnt/dockershm
docker run -d -v /mnt/dockershm:/dev/shm dockerimagetorun:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it may more appropriate to edit the global config for docker daemon, rather than set the value in docker-compose.yml or at the cli.

Here is the documentation for [Daemon configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)

Pick one method of editing the config:

1. On Docker Desktop you can go to `Settings->[Docker Engine]`.
2. On linux you may edit the default file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
3. On windows `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json`
4. On Mac `~/.docker/daemon.json`

Edit the config file to change the `shm` default size.

Example:

```
{
   ...
   "default-shm-size" : "128M"
   ...
}
```

After the change, restart docker may be required to relaod the config.

Comment: This is the only way to change the config when you don't have access to the docker-compose.yml file or the docker command in the cli. For example using the supabase cli that: in the background generates and starts a group of docker-compose services.

Comment: this is also useful for local mode of sagemaker jobs

Comment: Adding to @Davey's comment: this approach works, just remember to do `supabase stop` followed by `supabase start` to get the change effected.