# How can we define container parameters for Selenium dynamic grid?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

We just start using Dynamic Grid.
While running with the following configuration especially the screen resolution - chrome driver crashes.
But while removing the screen resolution we are able to run without any issues.
I assume this is related to the `shm_size` container parameter.
The new container receives default value of `shm_size` which is not enought.
How can I define `shm_size` container parameter for dynamically created container?

The configurations are:
**docker compose file**:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-docker:
    image: selenium/standalone-docker:4.9.0-20230421
    shm_size: "8gb"
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - ${PWD}/config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml
      - ${PWD}/assets:/opt/selenium/assets
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SE_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m
```

**config.toml file**:

```
[node]
detect-drivers = false
max-sessions = 100

[docker]
# Configs have a mapping between the Docker image to use and the capabilities that need to be matched to
# start a container with the given image.

configs = [
    "selenium/standalone-chrome:112.0-chromedriver-112.0-grid-4.9.0-20230421", '{"browserName": "chrome"}'
]

# URL for connecting to the docker daemon
# Most simple approach, leave it as http://127.0.0.1:2375, and mount /var/run/docker.sock.
# 127.0.0.1 is used because internally the container uses socat when /var/run/docker.sock is mounted
# If var/run/docker.sock is not mounted:
# Windows: make sure Docker Desktop exposes the daemon via tcp, and use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# macOS: install socat and run the following command, socat -4 TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock,
# then use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# Linux: varies from machine to machine, please mount /var/run/docker.sock. If this does not work, please create an issue.
url = "http://127.0.0.1:2375"
# Docker image used for video recording
video-image = "selenium/video:ffmpeg-6.1-20240224"

# Uncomment the following section if you are running the node on a separate VM
# Fill out the placeholders with appropriate values
#[server]
#host = <ip-from-node-machine>
#port = <port-from-node-machine>
```

**Driver chrome capabilities**:

```
chromeOptions.setCapability("se:recordVideo", true);
chromeOptions.setCapability("se:timeZone", "US/Pacific");
chromeOptions.setCapability("se:screenResolution", "1920x1200");
```

Comment: Not sure if you have tried this [shm size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210362/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-dev-shm-in-docker-container).